# shortening variable to x amount of characters without breaking html tags

Tags: php

currently working on a blog article preview system and have been using the following function to show a preview 400 chars of text and then place a ... at the end of the cut.

```
function ShortenText($text) {
        $chars = 400;
        $text = $text." ";
        $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
        $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));
        $text = $text."...";
        return $text;
 }
```

This has been working fine for sometime, today's post to the blog got cut half way through a html tag and busted the whole page.

is there any way to get this function to not cut html tags?

example $body content

```
   sdadasdasd<br><br>Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et mag<font size="5">na. Lorem ipsum</font> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum molli<span style="background-color: darkblue;">s mauris enim. <a href="url.html">Morbi</a> euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in </span>magna semper bibendum. Etiam scelerisque, nunc ac egestas consequat, odio nibh euismod nulla, eget auctor orci nibh vel nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris vel neque sit amet nunc gravida congue sed sit amet purus. Quisque lacus quam, egestas ac tincidunt a, lacinia vel velit. Aenean facilisis nulla vitae urna tincidunt congue sed ut dui. Mor<span style="color: midnightblue;">bi malesuada nulla nec purus convallis consequat. Vivamus id mollis quam. Morbi ac commodo nulla. In condimentum orci id nisl volutpat bibendum. Quisque commodo hendrerit lorem quis egestas. Maecenas quis tortor arcu. Vivamus rutrum nunc non neque consectetur quis placerat neque lobortis. Nam vestibulum, arcu sodales feugiat consectetur, nisl orci bibendum elit, eu euismod magna sapien ut nibh. Donec semper quam scelerisque tortor dictum gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam</span> eget molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla porta ligula egestas tincidunt. Nullam risus magna, ornare vitae varius eget, scelerisque a libero. Morbi eu porttitor ipsum. Nullam lorem.<br>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you create the tags yourself or do they come from somewhere?

Comment: the tags are being generated via a wysiwyg attached to a textarea in the back end, the only really issue is <a> tags at the moment. seems most browsers can handle the tag being broken, the new ff4 doesn't seem a fan though

Comment: Has the html code which surrounds your text always the same structure? Can you post an example?

Comment: the html can vary based on what the user puts in the wysiwyg, the template code is as follows

Comment: ['code']<div class='news-post-container'> 
 <div class='news-post'>
  <div class='news-post-title'>$pageTitle</div>
  <div class='news-post-cont'>
   <div class='news-post-cont-l'>
    <div class='news-post-date'><p>$pageDate</p></div>
    <div class='news-post-body'>";
  ShortenText($pageBody);
 </div>
    </div>
    <div class='news-post-cont-r'>
     <div class='news-small-img'>$pageimage</div>
     <div class='news-more'>
      <a href='" .BASE_URL. "/article.php?id=$pageID'>
       <img src='images/readmore.png'></a>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>['code']

Comment: Give us an example of the text that goes into `ShortenText()` and please post it in your question in a formatted way.

Comment: posted the content to one of my test entries,

Answer (score 1):

I don't there is any You could erase the html tags before calculating 400 chars

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
function ShortenText($text) {
     $text=strip_tags($text);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to keep the html formatting in tact for the preview

Comment: Then there's really no solution. What if you cut after an <h1>? The rest of your page will become a huge heading.

Comment: managed to work a solution so it can't be that impossible, and then you just make sure you don't cut before the tag is closed

Comment: @Xand94, it would be nice if you share your solution here.